# How to fetch all rows where an array contains any of the fields array elements

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, array-intersect

I have a table that has a column `video_ids`, it is of a `bigint[]` type. I would like to find all the rows that have any of the elements from the array passed in a select statement. So, if I have a row that has a `video_ids` field that looks like this:

```
{9529387, 9548200, 9579636}
```

I would like to fetch it if I pass an array that has any of this `video_ids`. I thought I would do that with any, but I am not sure how to do this in SQL, I have tried with this:

```
select id, finished, failed, video_ids, invoiced_video_ids, failed_video_ids
from video_order_execution
where order_ids = any(
    '{9548200, 11934626, 9579636, 11936321, 11509698, 11552728, 11592106, 11643565, 11707543, 11810386, 11846268}'
        ::bigint[]);
```

I get an error if I do that:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint[] = bigint Hint: No operator
> matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
> explicit type casts.

How can I make such a statement that would do the job for what I need?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Tag the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the operator [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) which returns `true` if the 2 operands have any common items:

```
select id, finished, failed, video_ids, invoiced_video_ids, failed_video_ids
from video_order_execution
where order_ids &&
  '{9548200, 11934626, 9579636, 11936321, 11509698, 11552728, 11592106, 11643565, 11707543, 11810386, 11846268}'::bigint[];
```